# Raspberry Pi 3 ,fann_create_standard not defined

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, raspberry-pi

I recently downloaded the FANN(Fast artificial neural network) library via the synaptic manager for raspberry pi. I am trying to run the default application as shown below:

```
 #include "fann.h"
 #include "floatfann.h"
 include "fann_data.h"

 int main()
 {
const unsigned int num_input = 2;
const unsigned int num_output = 1;
const unsigned int num_layers = 3;
const unsigned int num_neurons_hidden = 3;
const float desired_error = (const float) 0.001;
const unsigned int max_epochs = 500000;
const unsigned int epochs_between_reports = 1000;

struct fann *ann = fann_create_standard(num_layers, num_input,
    num_neurons_hidden, num_output);

fann_set_activation_function_hidden(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);
fann_set_activation_function_output(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);

fann_train_on_file(ann, "xor.data", max_epochs,
    epochs_between_reports, desired_error);

fann_save(ann, "xor_float.net");

fann_destroy(ann);

return 0;
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
enter code here


||=== Build: Debug in ArtificialNeuralNetworkExample (compiler: GNU GCC    Compi ler) ===|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `main':|
/home/pi/Documents/ArtificialNeuralNetworkExample/main.c|14|undefined reference to `fann_create_standard'|
/home/pi/Documents/ArtificialNeuralNetworkExample/main.c|17|undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_hidden'|
/home/pi/Documents/ArtificialNeuralNetworkExample/main.c|18|undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_output'|
/home/pi/Documents/ArtificialNeuralNetworkExample/main.c|20|undefined reference to `fann_train_on_file'|
/home/pi/Documents/ArtificialNeuralNetworkExample/main.c|23|undefined reference to `fann_save'|
/home/pi/Documents/ArtificialNeuralNetworkExample/main.c|25|undefined reference to `fann_destroy'|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Also tried linking the library using `gcc` as follows:

```
gcc -lfann main.c
```

Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you need to change the order in which the library appears in the compilation statement.

```
 gcc -lfann main.c
```

should be

```
 gcc main.c -lfann
```

as the functions used in `main.c` are present in `libfann.so`.

Quoting the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options),

> `-l library`
>
> [....] It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

In your case, you're facing similar scenario, for your case, the library should appear after the `main.c` as the functions from the library are used in `main.c`

Comment: Version is 2.1.0 if that helps.

Comment: I did this but am getting no output from terminal

Comment: Nvm, got it. Needed to type ./a.out for output

Comment: @Jon Cool!! You can also consider [accepting an answer that helped you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).